# TO make Grant I have error 1064 (42000)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am making a simple Grant in mysql, but wondering what is wrong with the below code.

```
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES 
    ON name_database.* 
    TO 'root'@'localhost'  
   IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'password';
```

Why I constantly get the error message like:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
syntax to use near
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES 
    ON name_database.* 
    TO 'root'@'localhost'  
   IDENTIFIED BY 'password'; /*<--- no PASSWORD KEYWORD*/
```